# My send() funnction is not working and the response is not shown in the localhost

Tags: localhost, backend, nodemon

//**I am posting my following question here and in short, the send() function is not working, The sentence in the response is not showing in the localhost**//

```
const express=require('express')


const app=express();




app.get("/",function(req,res){
    console.log(req)
    res.send("This is localhost response")
    
    
    })






app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('The server is listening ');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req);
      res.json("WORKING!!!");

});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("The server is listening ");
});
```

Comment: The code is still not working; let me specify the problem;
There is a small dotted underline in my VS code IDE that says the error:File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES module
And after I run it using nodemon, The server is taking to long to respond, and  not showing anything.
It is behaving as if I have sent nothing from my side, Although all the other things are working absolutely fine, just not showing up on the browser.

Comment: @Tyler2P Tahnk you for the sugession, I shall try that.